# merging and then sorting 2 arrays in php & wordpress

Tags: php, arrays, wordpress, sorting

I'm trying to merge 2 arrays in PHP and then sort them.

I'm pulling data from WordPress database ( tags and categories ) and I need to merge them and sort them properly.

Code looks similar to this:

```
$categories = [ 
  '<a>WordPress Tips</a>',
  '<a>SEO Tips'</a>, 
  '<a>Development Tips</a>' 
]; 

$tags = [ 
  '<a>WordPress</a>',
  '<a>SEO'</a>, 
  '<a>Development</a>' 
]; 

$taxonomies = array_merge($categories, $tags);
sort($taxonomies);
```

Since I need to loop through $taxonomies array and print them with anchors included ( every one of those must have a valid URL to itself ), I don't get a proper sorting result. However, as soon as I 'strip out' all the tags around these items, sorting works as it should, but I don't get URLs that I need, only string / text.

Could someone suggest a better sorting algorithm which would sort these items properly with html elements included around them? Thanks!

Comment: Use [uasort](http://php.net/manual/en/function.uasort.php)?

Comment: Tried it, as I've tried all other native PHP sorting functions. Not working.

Comment: Then add the code that you tried so we can help you fix it. usort/uasort seems to be the solution here.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to do custom comaprision to make it work using [usort()](http://php.net/manual/en/function.usort.php) and [strip_tags()](http://php.net/manual/en/function.strip-tags.php)

```
<?php
$taxonomies = array_merge($categories, $tags);
print_r($taxonomies);
function cmp($a, $b){
    $data1 = strip_tags($a);
    $data2 = strip_tags($b);
    return ($data1 < $data2) ? -1 : 1;
}
usort($taxonomies, "cmp");
print_r($taxonomies);
```

Output:-https://eval.in/934071

Comment: Yes exactly what I said in my comment. In addition you can make an anonymous function (callable) for "cmp" to avoid any possible conflicts with the name.

Comment: @kneles90  glad to help you:):)

Comment: Sorry mate, didn't know. Thanks a lot again!

Answer (score 2):

Since you mentioned that the tags stripped version works, a simple way might be to use them as the keys in the sort. Something like this, for instance :

```
$taxonomies = array_merge( $categories, $tags );
$toSort = [];
foreach($taxonomies as $tax) {
  $toSort[strip_tags($tax)] = $tax;
}

ksort( $toSort );
print_r( $toSort );
```

Which will give the sorted array and you can just use the values in there. Maybe there's better options but this comes to mind off the top of my head..

EDIT : uasort with a comparision function that actually compares the stripped versions might be better, after looking at other answers here.

Comment: Thanks man, I've used that array, looped through it and works great!

Comment: Still, don't know why all the downvotes on my post :)

Comment: This solution will fail if there is the same item both in $categories and $tags.

Comment: I can always test for uniqueness. It just might happen that categories and tags have the same name, why exclude duplicates then?

Comment: @rlanvin true, but the failure is not because of the sorting, but the array merge, no?

Comment: @AbhiyanPaudyal  no. Please check:- https://eval.in/934078   And  https://eval.in/934079

Comment: Very correct. For some reason I was blocking out the index difference. Thanks!